# ChartView within StackLayout cuts off Chart

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Here is my code:

```
List<Entry> entries = new List<Entry>
{
    new Entry(7)  
    {
        Color = SKColor.Parse("#166DA3"),
    },
    new Entry(3) 
    {
        Color = SKColors.Transparent,
    }
};

public RoundScore2()
{
    Content = _contentLayout; // layout inherited from a different class 


    Label congrats = new Label
    {
        Text = "Congratulations!",
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
        FontSize = 30,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        TextColor = Color.Black
    };

    _contentStack.Children.Add(congrats); // _contentStack inherited from same class, _contentStack is added to _contentLayout



    ChartView Chart1 = new ChartView
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        HeightRequest = 80

    };

    _contentStack.Children.Add(Chart1);

    Chart1.Chart = new DonutChart() { Entries = entries, HoleRadius = 5 };


    Button nextRound = new Button
    {
        Text = "Start Round " + roundCounter.ToString(),
        Margin = new Thickness(10, 20, 10, 10),
        TextColor = Color.Black, 
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("48AADF"),
        FontFamily = "Source Sans Pro",
        FontSize = 20,
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
        CornerRadius = 8,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
        WidthRequest = 180

    };
    _contentStack.Children.Add(nextRound);


}
```

Stack overflow is not letting me add the photo right now ("Failed to upload image; couldn't reach imgur")...but basically, I can only see the horizontal middle section of the pie chart. There is enough space for the chart to show, but it is just cut off. I have tried setting `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` along with `LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand` and no luck. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Edit: even with the Label and Button taken out, the view is still cut off.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the charting library, but what happens if you set the chart type (the whole new Donut) before we add it to the contentstack's children?

Comment: No change after trying this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after changing `VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center` and `HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill` as well as changing `HoleRadius = .5f`.

Answer (score 0):

> but basically, I can only see the horizontal middle section of the pie chart.

From shared code of `ChartView`, I'm guessing that whether the width of chart view is too small.

```
ChartView Chart1 = new ChartView
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HeightRequest = 80

};
```

If so , you can add `HorizontalOptions` as follow:

```
ChartView Chart1 = new ChartView
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    HeightRequest = 80

};
```

In addition , also can add `HorizontalOptions` for `StackLayout`:

```
_contentStack.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
_contentStack.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
```

Comment: @11thal11thal Okey , mabye the effect is affected by the content of `ChartView`. Could you share the code of `ChartView`, I will check that in local site.